# wx.Gauge fails to update beyond 25% in Windows, works in Linux

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I seem to have nothing but trouble with wxPython and cross-platform compatibility :(

I have the function below. It's called when the user clicks a button, it does some work which may take a while, during which a progress gauge is shown in the status bar.

```
def Go(self, event):       
    progress = 0
    self.statbar.setprogress(progress)
    self.Update()

    # ...

    for i in range(1, numwords + 1):
        progress = int(((float(i) / float(numwords)) * 100) - 1)
        self.wrdlst.Append(words.next())
        self.statbar.setprogress(progress)
        self.Update()

    self.wrdlst.Refresh() 

    # ...

    progress = 100
    self.PushStatusText(app.l10n['msc_genwords'] % numwords)        
    self.statbar.setprogress(progress)
```

The calls to `self.Update()` are apparently needed under Linux, otherwise the gauge doesn't update until the function exits which makes it kinda pointless. These calls seem to have no effect under Windows (Win 7 at least).

The whole thing works perfectly under Linux (with the calls to Update()), but on Windows 7 the gauge seems to stop around the 20-25% mark, a while before the function exits. So it moves as it should until it reaches ~25%, then the gauge stops moving for no apparent reason but the function continues on just fine and exits with the proper output.

In my attempt to find out the problem, I tried inserting a `print progress` line just before updating the gauge inside the loop, thinking maybe the value of `progress` wasn't what I thought it should be. To my big surprise, the gauge now worked as it should, but the moment I remove that `print` it stops working. I can also replace the print with a call to `time.sleep(0.001)`, but even with such a short sleep the process still grinds to almost a halt, and if I lower it even further the problem returns, so it's hardly very helpful.

I can't figure out what is going on or how to fix it, but I guess somehow things move too fast under Windows so that `progress` doesn't get updated properly after a while and just stays at a fixed value (~25). I have no idea why that would be, however, it makes no sense to me. And of course, neither `print` nor `sleep` are good solutions. Even if I print out "nothing", Windows still opens another window for the non-existent output, which is annoying.

Let me know if you need further info or code.

**Edit:** Ok, here's a working application which (for me at least) has the problem. It's still pretty long, but I tried to cut out everything not related to the problem at hand.

It works on Linux, just like the complete app. Under Windows it either fails or works depending on the value of `numwords` in the Go function. If I increase its value to 1000000 (1 million) the problem goes away. I suspect this may depend on the system, so if it works for you try to tweak the value of `numwords`. It may also be because I changed it so it `Append()`s a static text rather than calling a generator as it does in the original code.

Still, with the current value of `numwords` (100000) it does fail on Windows for me.

```
import wx

class Wordlist(wx.TextCtrl):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Wordlist, self).__init__(parent,
                                       style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.words = []
        self.SetValue("")

    def Get(self):
        return '\r\n'.join(self.words)

    def Refresh(self):
        self.SetValue(self.Get())

    def Append(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = '\r\n'.join(value)        
        self.words.append(unicode(value))

class ProgressStatusBar(wx.StatusBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProgressStatusBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._changed = False

        self.prog = wx.Gauge(self, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.prog.Hide()

        self.SetFieldsCount(2)
        self.SetStatusWidths([-1, 150])

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, lambda evt: self.__reposition())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onsize)

    def __reposition(self): 
        if self._changed:
            lfield = self.GetFieldsCount() - 1
            rect = self.GetFieldRect(lfield)
            prog_pos = (rect.x + 2, rect.y + 2)
            self.prog.SetPosition(prog_pos)
            prog_size = (rect.width - 8, rect.height - 4)
            self.prog.SetSize(prog_size)
        self._changed = False

    def onsize(self, evt):
        self._changed = True
        self.__reposition()
        evt.Skip()

    def setprogress(self, val):
        if not self.prog.IsShown():
            self.showprogress(True)

        if val == self.prog.GetRange():
            self.prog.SetValue(0)
            self.showprogress(False)
        else:
            self.prog.SetValue(val)

    def showprogress(self, show=True):
        self.__reposition()
        self.prog.Show(show)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.SetupControls()

        self.statbar = ProgressStatusBar(self)
        self.SetStatusBar(self.statbar)

        self.panel.Fit()
        self.SetInitialSize()
        self.SetupBindings()

    def SetupControls(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.gobtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Go")                               
        self.wrdlst = Wordlist(self.panel)

        wrap = wx.BoxSizer()
        wrap.Add(self.gobtn, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        wrap.Add(self.wrdlst, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(wrap)

    def SetupBindings(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Go, self.gobtn)

    def Go(self, event):       
        progress = 0
        self.statbar.setprogress(progress)
        self.Update()

        numwords = 100000

        for i in range(1, numwords + 1):
            progress = int(((float(i) / float(numwords)) * 100) - 1)
            self.wrdlst.Append("test " + str(i))
            self.statbar.setprogress(progress)
            self.Update()

        self.wrdlst.Refresh()

        progress = 100
        self.statbar.setprogress(progress)

class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        framestyle = wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CAPTION|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|\
                     wx.CLIP_CHILDREN
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, title="test", style=framestyle)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Center()
        self.frame.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Edit 2**: Below is an even simpler version of the code. I don't think I can make it much smaller. It still has the problem for me. I can run it from within IDLE, or directly by double clicking the .py file in Windows, either way works the same.

I tried with various values of `numwords`. It seems the problem doesn't actually go away as I first said, instead when I increase `numwords` the gauge just reaches further and further before the `print` is called. At the current value of 1.000.000 this shorter version reaches around 50%. In the longer version above, a value of 1.000.000 reaches around 90%, a value of 100.000 reaches around 25%, and a value of 10.000 only reaches around 10%.

In the version below, once the `print` is called, the progress continues on and reaches 99% even though the loop must have ended by then. In the original version the call to `self.wrdlst.Refresh()`, which takes a few seconds when numwords is high, must have caused the gauge to pause. So I think that what happens is this: In the loop the gauge only reaches a certain point, when the loop exits the function continues on while the gauge stays still, and when the function exits the gauge continues on until it reaches 99%. Because a print statement doesn't take a lot of time, the version below makes it seem like the gauge moves smoothly from 0% to 99%, but the `print` suggests otherwise.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)        
        self.gobtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Go")
        self.prog = wx.Gauge(self, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        wrap = wx.BoxSizer()
        wrap.Add(self.gobtn, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        wrap.Add(self.prog, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(wrap)
        self.panel.Fit()
        self.SetInitialSize()        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Go, self.gobtn)

    def Go(self, event):        
        numwords = 1000000
        self.prog.SetValue(0)
        for i in range(1, numwords + 1):
            progress = int(((float(i) / float(numwords)) * 100) - 1)
            self.prog.SetValue(progress)
        print "Done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal, functional code reproducing your problem? Otherwise it is difficult to check what is going on

Comment: Done. Still a little long, but I hope that helps.

Comment: your code works perfect on win 7. By the way you dont need to convert everything to float in the loop

Comment: It doesn't work for me, at least not always. Did you try changing the value of numwords as I mentioned? And yeah, the floats (and many parentheses) are remains from when I thought perhaps it was that line not working right.

Comment: it works for me either for numwords=1000 (very fast but still I can see the bar arriving to the end) and for numwords=1000000. Sorry can not help.

Comment: That's odd, but I suppose if it's only me then it may not be a serious issue. What version of python/wxpython do you use?

Comment: 2.8.12.0, 64-bit, active python 2.6.6.18

Comment: Hmm, I have 2.8.11, though the same python version. Maybe I'll try updating wxPython and see what happens

Comment: Still got the problem after upgrading to 2.8.12

Comment: weird, I already supossed the version was not important in this case. Maybe you could reduce the code to the minimal expression that produce that behavior and try it in other computers... Maybe it is a question of PC resources (memory, speed, graphic card...). Are you running the program from an IDE?. Also you said that the problem disappears increasing numwords. Is There a critical value between 100.000 and 1.000.000 ? What happens around that point?

Comment: Did a much shorter version and some more testing. See second edit above.

Comment: really interesting... i can not see the effect anyway. in my case the print takes place only after the gauge arrives to the end. At low numwords it is so fast that it is difficult to say.

Comment: Your last example works perectly on my computer: Windows XP SP3, Python 2.7.1, wxPython: 2.8.12.0.

Comment: @mcxxiii: your question would be much more understandable if you removed all the edits and just rewrote the question with one version of your code.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I know it's ended up being pretty long. I thought perhaps there might be helpful details in there, however, so I left it as it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, actually, **you are blocking the GUI thread** by your long running task. It may and may not run fine on some platforms and/or computers.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.delayedresult import startWorker

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)        
        self.gobtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Go")
        self.prog = wx.Gauge(self, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)

        wrap = wx.BoxSizer()
        wrap.Add(self.gobtn, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        wrap.Add(self.prog, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(wrap)
        self.panel.Fit()
        self.SetInitialSize()        

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Go, self.gobtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)


    def Go(self, event):
        # Start actual work in another thread and start timer which 
        # will periodically check the progress and draw it
        startWorker(self.GoDone, self.GoCompute)
        self.progress = 0
        self.timer.Start(100)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        # Timer draws the progress
        self.prog.SetValue(self.progress)

    def GoCompute(self):
        # This method will run in another thread not blocking the GUI
        numwords = 10000000
        self.prog.SetValue(0)
        for i in range(1, numwords + 1):
            self.progress = int(((float(i) / float(numwords)) * 100) - 1)

    def GoDone(self, result):
        # This is called when GoCompute finishes
        self.prog.SetValue(100)
        self.timer.Stop()
        print "Done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Also notice that contrary your example:

- Button goes back to unclicked state after clicked
- You can move the window and it will not freeze

As a rule of thumb, every method which looks like this `def Something(self, event)` should run just a few milliseconds.

**EDIT:** Another thing what I have observed on Windows 7. The gauge **starts** to grow at the time you call `self.prog.SetValue()` and grows in some time to specified value. It does not "jump" to that value, rather it grows slowly to hit set value. It seems to be Windows 7 feature. I had to switch off "Animate controls and element inside windows" in performance options to get rid of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly your code still produces the problem for me, the print is called before the gauge reaches the end. I had been wanting to put the long-running part into a separate thread eventually, however I haven't worked with threads much before, so thanks for the example.

Comment: OK, THAT is really weird. So you say that you see the print and the gauge is at what %? I would try a clean Windows install in VMWare (can be downloaded for free). Because I am calling `self.prog.SetValue(100)` right before `print "Done"`. Try slowing down the timer, for example to `self.timer.Start(500)`.

Comment: Another thing what I have observed on Windows 7. The gauge **starts** to grow at the time you call `self.prog.SetValue()` and grows in some time to specified value. It does not "jump" to that value, rather it grows slowly to hit set value. It seems to be Windows 7 feature. It may or may not be related to your problem. I had to switch off "Animate controls and element inside windows" in performance options to get rid of this behavior.

Comment: HA! That was it. Apparently Windows was just behind on its animation, even while the program had long finished. Thanks, I'd never have figured that out. Now I only wonder if there's some way to circumvent this within the code, rather than relying on the user to change the settings of Windows.

Comment: I do not really see that as a "problem", that is probably normal behavior of all the programs under Windows and user should not really bother. You just say "Done" and set gauge to 100%. On my computer it takes about 1 second to finish the animation. I did not notice until now, because all applications I know use dialogs with gauges and close them as soon as they finish the long running task.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose. It does seem a little silly when the gauge says you're done at 25%, but as long as it's not a problem with my code I can live with it. Thanks for solving the mystery.

Comment: Yeah, it can look a bit odd if you do not close the window with gauge and you have a bit slow machine for example.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy for about 6 months since my work upgraded my computer from XP to W7.  I have a few scripts that work just right in XP and Linux, but had this same problem in W7.  It bugged the heck out of me.  Turning off the stupid "Animate controls and element inside windows" seems to have fixed the problem for me too.  Just sucks that it will be wrong looking for other users of my code though....very frustrating.

Comment: I guess you should be able to change the settings using registry. You may ask the user if he wants it to be switched off to improve the gauge accuracy.